# Hybrid SmartSync app crash - setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: Customfield__c)' exception

Tags: mobilesdk

I am using the latest Cordova plugin for Salesforce Mobile and when I try to use Smartsync, my app crashes with

```
setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: Customfield__c)' exception.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using latest Cordova plugin? It has been a known issue but resolved last week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AzZkIAK) thread. This was a known issue which is now fixed - Either update your local repo from here or pull down the latest `libSmartSync.a` file from the repo.

[This](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/issues/41) is the link to the github issue which is now marked as fixed.